# gapi.client.plus.people.get returns 403 error

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I am working on an appengine project for a webpage.
I turned on the Google+ API in the developers console.
The webpage logs in as:

```
userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI())
```

After that I want to retreive the profile picture of the user that is logged in.
For this I imported the js-libraries:

```
<script src = "https://plus.google.com/js/client:platform.js" async defer></script>
```

and:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And then I execute:

```
gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
    var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
        'userId': 'me'
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
        console.log('Image at:' + resp.image.url);
    });
});
```

But this keeps on returning an 403 error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

How can I solve this? What am I missing?

Comment: The error seems clear, you've exceeded the daily limit for unauthenticated users, so you either wait, or you authenticate ?

Answer (score 1):

I cant comment so I am writing an answer for it.

Go to the google developer console:

- select your project.
- go to API & Auth on the left hand side panel.
- select the API that you are using.
- click on the usage tab and see the number of requests that you are making.

The number of requests must be exceeding the daily free limit of the API you are trying to use.

Comment: The problem is that these quota are still all at 100% (I haven't used any quota).